# Is there command to show all bluetooth devices ever conencted to my mobile phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

So i lost my bluetooth ear buds and wonder if there is any way i can see where i was lastly connected to them. I had already tried using command *adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager* but the command only showed bluetooth devices from this day. Is there any command that can show at least 3 days back?

Comment: Please consider to post you question over at the [Android StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) as well